# Reversed continuity

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity

We know that if a function $f$ satisfies
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x_n) = f(x_0),\qquad (1)$$
where $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n = x_0$, than $f$ is continuous at the point $x_0$. But can we reverse this statement? What I mean by that is, if we already know that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, can we say that $(1)$ must be true?

Comment: Do you mean to obtain from above $\epsilon - \delta$ definition?

Comment: That is the definition, so of course that if $f$ is continuous limit mentioned above must exist, again by definition. This is not $A \iff B$ statemend because you defined $B$ by $A$.

Comment: I've seen loads of questions like this on math.se. So this is likely a duplicate question.

Comment: There are a couple of issues with your question.  First, the initial statement is wrong---you are, at the very least, missing a quantifier.  If $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n) = f(x_0)$ for all sequences of $x_n$ such that $x_n \to x_0$, then $f$ is continuous.  Second, answering your question requires that you first give a definition of continuity.  Of course, in many contexts, the statement I've given **is** the definition of continuity, so of course a continuous function satisfies this property.  If you define continuity differently, then you have to do a little more work.

Answer (score 2):

Your statement is wrong ! Take $f=\boldsymbol 1_{\left\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n\in\mathbb N\right\}}$ and $x_n=\frac{\pi}{n}$. Then $f(x_n)\to f(0)$, but $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

The statement should be :

> $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if **for all** $(x_n)$ s.t. $x_n\to x_0$, we have $$\lim_{n\to \infty }f(x_n)=f(x_0).$$

Comment: Yes but can you reverse it?

Comment: Does the bold 1 in the question mean the indicator function?

Comment: @Daniel: yes absolutely (prove it !)

Comment: @AdamRubinson: yes it is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a definition, which should be interpreted as an "if and only if" statement rather than an "if" statement, even though definition are usually written using only "if". So $f$ is continuous at the point $x_0$ *if and only if* whenever $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = x_0$, we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)=f(x_0)$.

For another example, you'll often see the definition "$n$ is even if $n=2k$ for some integer $k$". But really $n$ is even if *and only if* $n=2k$ for some integer $k$. Whenever you are dealing with definitions, you should think of the condition as an "if and only if".

Comment: Exatcly. First statement is actually quite important and worth emphasizing

Comment: "Whenever you are dealing with definitions, you should think of the condition as an "if and only if"." Should I read that as "something is a definition if and only one should think of it as 'if and only if'"?

Comment: @Acccumulation No, I wouldn't say that. There is an integer solution to $a^n+b^n=c^n$ if and only if $n=1$ or $n=2$, but I wouldn't say that's a definition of the set $\{1,2\}$.

Answer (score 0):

There is well known definition [In terms of sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function) by Eduard Heine, by which function is continuous in $x_0$ when for $\forall x_n \to x_0, \exists N, n>N, x_n \ne x_0$ (your initial statement leaks conditions on $x_n$) we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x_n) = f(x_0)$ and it is equivalent to classical Cauchy $\epsilon - \delta$  definition.

So if function is continuous by Cauchy, then your (1) holds.